# Горизонтальное размещение элементов в RecyclerView

Tags: android

1. В приложении ivi.ru как я понял используется recyclerview и несколько элементов расположены по горизонтали в одной строке. Если перевернуть устройство то в эту строку помещаются побольше элементов.  внизу прикрепил скриншот. Как сделать также, чтобы было несколько элементов?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду два два прокручиваемых списка? Не совсем понятен вопрос

Comment: Нет один список чтобы было по несколько элементов в одну строчку. Можно ли так?

Comment: Ну если вы используете список, то соответственно будет видно столько элементов, на сколько соответствует ширина дисплея, а остальное в прокрутке. Ведь это список у которого есть определенная длина, и он до конца своей длины прокручивается, так как дисплей слишком мал для отображения всей длины списка.

Comment: На вашем скриншоте изображено не то, о чем вы спрашиваете в вопросе. На скриншоте горизонтальные списки, которые находятся в вертикальном списке (прокручивается каждый айтем по горизонтали и все они по вертикали). Сделать такой интерфейс [довольно сложно](http://android-pratap.blogspot.ru/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html). Если вам нужно просто размещать больше элементов при повороте, то это решается [небольшим усовершенствованием](https://codentrick.com/part-4-android-recyclerview-grid/) стандартного GridLayoutManager (auto column)

Comment: Понял. Думал можно в recyclerview вывести таким образом

Comment: То что нужно. Спасибо.